# How do I navigate to another screen from a screen opened by drawer in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to navigate like this (it was working fine when I had not made the drawer):

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects')}></Button>
```

But after adding the drawer, and on pressing button I am getting an error like this:

```
console.error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload '{"name":"Projects"}' was not handled by any navigator.
```

This is my drawer code:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={AccountantScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="My Account" component={MyAccountScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function DrawerLeft() {
  return (

    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
```

This is my App.js:

```
import ProjectsScreen from './screens/Accountant/ProjectsScreen';

import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const FirstNavGroup = createSwitchNavigator({
    Projects: {
       screen: ProjectsScreen
    },

export default createAppContainer(FirstNavGroup)
```

How do I navigate to the Projects page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix react-navigation v4 with v5:

`Drawer.Navigator` is using v5 syntax, and `createSwitchNavigator` does not exist anymore.

Comment: What should I use in place of createSwitchNavigator?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing v4 and v5 of React-Navigation.

> createAppContainer is from v4
>   NavigationContainer is from v5

I would suggest you to fully switch to v5. It should fix your problem.

I don't understand why you need switch navigator. In your situation, you can use stack navigator.

Here's the example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator